# Lisp two lists, get items from each list to be together

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I have two list like follows

List 1  ((item 1 5 9) (item 2 50 15) (item 3 39 99) (item 4 16 79) (item 5 20 96))

List 2 ( (1 0 1 0 1) (1 1 1 1 1) (1 0 1 0 1))

I want it to be like

(item 1 5 9) (1)
(item 2 50 15) (0)
(item 3 39 99) (1)
(item 4 16 79) (0)
(item 4 16 79) (1)

And does this for each chromosome. I have the following code so far

```
(defun print-Lists (list1 list2)
(loop for x in list1
      for y in list2
      collect (print(list x y) ))
)
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

I do not fully grasp your example, but maybe something like this would help?

```
(loop for x in '((1 1 1) (1 0 1))
      append (mapcan (lambda (a b) (list a (list b)))
                     '((item 1 2 3) (item 4 5 6) (item 7 8 9))
                     x))
```

which evaluates to:

```
((ITEM 1 2 3) (1) (ITEM 4 5 6) (1) (ITEM 7 8 9) (1) (ITEM 1 2 3) (1)
(ITEM 4 5 6) (0) (ITEM 7 8 9) (1))
```

translated to your example this would look like

```
(loop for x in list2
      append (mapcan (lambda (a b) (list a (list b)))
                     list1
                     x))
```

(If you would rather have each iteration in a seperate list, change append to collect.)

You can then simply print the resulting list with

```
(format t "~{~A ~A~%~}" result-list)
```

or something similar.

Keep in mind that this only works if the length of the items in list2 matches the length of list1.

For more information on mapcan you can visit

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm

Regards, K.

Answer (score 2):

The last 3 questions you have asked really say you need to loop at map, reduce and higher order functions in general. Lisp has some great tools but if you jsut use what you know you will not experience any benefits.

```
(defvar a '((item 1 5 9) (item 2 50 15) (item 3 39 99) (item 4 16 79) (item 5 20 96)))
(defvar b '(1 0 1 0 1))

> (mapcan (lambda (x y) (list x (list y))) a b)
((ITEM 1 5 9) (1) (ITEM 2 50 15) (0) (ITEM 3 39 99) (1) (ITEM 4 16 79) (0) (ITEM 5 20 96) (1))
```

It is not *exactly* what you asked for but it should show you the way.

I'm serious though about the functional stuff. Check out [this book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html), it is a free and may help you.